# VS2022 17.5.4 for ARM does not load Xamarin Forms project with Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

I am running Windows 11 Pro & trying to open a Xamarin Forms solution with an Android project in the latest VS2022 Community version and I get the error below

> The application which this project type is based on was not found

I get this link in the migration report which takes me to VS2022 download http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF

This seem to work fine on the latest VS2022 preview installed side by side.

I would appreicate any advice or guidance

Comment: 1. You can try to use the VS installer to repair the installation `VS2022 17.5.4`. 2. You can also post your issue in [Developer Community - VS Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio) to get professional support from VS technical support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reminding about the community forum Alexander.

I have searched the forum and it seems this is not supported yet in VS 2022 17.5.4 based on this thread. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin--XamarinForms-workload-option/10157386?q=arm+xamarin+2022

It works fine in VS 2022 Preview 17.6 though, so we might have to wait for that to release.

Comment: My pleasure! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.